# A python script does not work from command line in contrast to running it from ipython

Tags: python, ipython, langchain

The following code reports an error when executed from the command line, whereas it executes fine from ipython (line by line). The script uses a locally-stored HuggingFace model, reads a scientific paper from a pdf file and answers questions about the paper.

```
import os
os.environ["HUGGINGFACEHUB_API_TOKEN"] = 'hf-xxxxxx'

from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain import HuggingFaceHub
from langchain.llms import HuggingFacePipeline
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM, pipeline, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM

model_id = 'google/flan-t5-large'
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id,max_length=1500)

model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(model_id)

pipe = pipeline("text2text-generation", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, max_length=1500)
llm = HuggingFacePipeline(pipeline=pipe)

from langchain.document_loaders import UnstructuredPDFLoader
from langchain.indexes import VectorstoreIndexCreator
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter

pdf_folder_path = "/mnt/d/test/langchain/pdfs"
loaders = [UnstructuredPDFLoader(os.path.join(pdf_folder_path, fn)) for fn in os.listdir(pdf_folder_path)]

index = VectorstoreIndexCreator(
   embedding=HuggingFaceEmbeddings(),
   text_splitter=CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=0)).from_loaders(loaders)

from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=llm,
                                    chain_type="stuff",
                                    retriever=index.vectorstore.as_retriever(),
                                    input_key="question")

chain.run('What method was used in calculations?')
```

Here is the error when running from the command line (using `python script.py`):

```
Token indices sequence length is longer than the specified maximum sequence length for this model (1142 > 512). Running this sequence through the model will result in indexing errors
Exception ignored in: <function DuckDB.__del__ at 0x7f0d0b1b1fc0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/popsi/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/db/duckdb.py", line 355, in __del__
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'info'
```

When executing from ipython I get the warning similar to the command-line run but without the error in DuckDB:

```
Token indices sequence length is longer than the specified maximum sequence length for this model (1142 > 512). Running this sequence through the model will result in indexing errors
```

and the program finishes correctly with correct answers.

I believe python (command line) and ipython may depend on different environment variable or something similar but I cannot find on the Internet the solution to this problem. Any idea?

**EDIT:** When I use `print(chain.run('What method was used in calculations?'))` instead of the last line stated above, then even the command-line-run prints the answer. However the error message about `__del__` of duckdb.py is still reported at the end. I am not a Python expert but I suppose that `__del__` is a destructor of object duckdb which is called at the end of the script execution. From the ipython the destructor is never called since program never ends during run of ipython. Is it a correct reasoning? If so, there might be a bug in DuckDB.

Comment: You could inspect your environment variables `os.environ` in a debugger running on your graphical application to determine what is different. Also this [GitHub PR](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/pull/1833) might be of some help

Comment: it could also be that your python environements have different versions of the library you are using. Try perhaps `python -m langchain --version` or `python -m pip freeze | grep langchain` -- and compare with the same commands with ipython

Comment: @AlexLoss Thank you for suggestions. I checked the environemnt vars as you suggested and they are the same in ipython and bash shell from where I run python command line. Also versions of langchain are the same.